# JWT correct behaviour with invalid credentials

Tags: java, authentication, jwt

I would like to ask how to behave correctly when server receives user credentials which are not valid (username or password does not fit).

Should server send back an empty jwt token and set HttpStatus for 401
or is there any other preferable way?